# Altering the rows contained in an SSRS row group

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a report which currently has a sum row following a hierarchical row grouping. The sum row is not part of the group, but I would like to incorporate it into a new parent level grouping to provide sub-totalling as the new top level grouping changes.

[image]

The indicated row is the one I would like to include in a new parent grouping above the current top level group. I can add an additional parent grouping, but am struggling with how to include the net cost of service row into that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on the row above the current sub-total row, you can "Insert Row - Outside Group Below". This will add a row below that is part of the second to last group. If you repeat this, it will do it below but for the group level above. Repeat until you have the desired group level - then delete the unwanted rows.

Comment: That worked a treat thank you. I needed to copy the content up into the new row once I had it in the desired group, but I was expecting that to be the case.